# What does 'state' mean regarding Django apps?

Tags: python, django, review-board

I'm new to django (and programming in general) and I am trying to create a Reviewboard extension.
This extension will display the fullname of the user in a column. The code works for the most part, however I don't understand what the state variable in this method does.

```
    # renders column to display
    def render_data(self, state, review_request):
        # returns user's fullname (or username if fullname does not exist)
        user = review_request.submitter
        return user.get_full_name() or user.username
```

This code works, however when I remove the 'state' argument, the field shows 'None' instead of the fullname of the user. I tried looking online but I could not find an explanation for what that variable does.

I dont even call it in my method, yet it still affects the result.

I don't like having code that I don't fully understand (harder to debug), so could someone shed some light on this?

**What I think it means**

I think state refers to the instance of  the object. In this case it would be the review_request that the fullname is being rendered for. Without this instance, one review request can't be differentiated from all of them. I still don't know how it affects the code without me even calling it.

Edit: C14L was right, I renamed state to foobar and my code still functioned properly. I dug a bit more into the [source](https://github.com/djblets/djblets/blob/master/djblets/datagrid/grids.py) of the djblets/django code where it calls the function.

```
rendered_data = self.render_data(state, obj)
```

Comment: In the code you posted, `state` isn't used at all. But, if you remove it, then `review_request` will be the second argument. But this function is called, expecting `review_request` to be the third argument. You can't just change the number or order of arguments, because the callers don't know about that. Try renaming `state` into `foobar` and the function will still work as before.

Comment: Thank you!
Renaming state to foobar did not change the output. I may just need to keep some sort of 'placeholder' in order to eat up the second argument.

Would it be non-pythonic to simply keep the placeholder there? Or should I try to find a workaround?

Comment: Also, can you post your comment as an answer, as it does answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, `state` isn't used at all. But, if you remove it, then `review_request` will be the second argument. But this function is called, expecting `review_request` to be the third argument. You can't just change the number or order of arguments, because the callers don't know about that. Try renaming `state` to `foobar` and the function will still work as before.

You can just leave `state` there, that's perfectly fine. The interface of the function/method shouldn't change only because one of the arguments isn't used (anymore) inside the function or method.